# Cannot Use File or nio to check existence of a file in Pipeline, NonCPS or Shared Library

Tags: java, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Any idea what makes master so special to cause this code to succeed there and fail elsewhere?  I'm going to check java version and classpath next.

The following code properly detects file existence via each of the following way if run on master.  If run on any slave, it fails to do so.

I'm writing a share library and have many unit test.  I don't want to use `fileExists()` pipeline code because then I need to:

- pass script object throughout my generic code making it jenkins centric
- refactor unit tests to fake out the fileExists method when not run in jenkins.

PipelineCode for Parameterized Job with NODE param:

```
import java.nio.file.Path
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.nio.file.Files

import hudson.FilePath




def isreg(def path) {
    Path target = Paths.get(path)
    println "Checking ${target} // ${target.toAbsolutePath()}"
    println "target is reg? ${Files.isRegularFile(target)}"
    println "target is reg? ${Files.isRegularFile(target.toAbsolutePath())}"
}

def exists(def path) {
    Path target = Paths.get(path)
    println "Checking ${target} // ${target.toAbsolutePath()}"
    println "target exists? ${Files.exists(target)}"
    println "target exists? ${Files.exists(target.toAbsolutePath())}"
    println "File exists ${target.toFile().exists()} ${target.toAbsolutePath().toFile().exists()}"

}

def filePathExists(def path) {
    FilePath fPath = new FilePath(new File(path))
    println "FilePath ${fPath} exists? ${fPath.exists()}"
}

def checkFile(def target) {
    println "----------\nnio isReg"
    isreg(target)
    println "----------\nnio exists"
    exists(target)

    println "----------\n FilePath exists"
    filePathExists(target)

}


node(params.NODE) {
    currentBuild.description = "run on ${params.NODE}"
    def target = "${env.WORKSPACE}/target.txt"
    sh "touch ${target}"
    checkFile(target)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipeline is executed on master and therefore, even within a shareLibrary, you must use pipeline's fileExists method and not File or NIO objects.

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/230922128-Pipeline-Using-java-io-File-in-a-Pipeline-description